# How to get HTML Input Element tag with jquery class selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

How do I get this:

```
var address = document.getElementById('address1');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(address);
```

With jQuery using this:

```
$('.addressClass input')
```

Assume I have a input tag with class: addressClass. Just not sure how to apply the autocomplete JS functionality with jQuery. How to get tag element with jQuery.
I can't just do this can I:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('.addressClass input'));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a 3rd answer notification, but can't see the answer here...Not sure if that answer has been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**.get()**](http://api.jquery.com/get/), it retrieves the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('.addressClass input').get(0));
```

OR

You can access element using index `[0]`

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('.addressClass input')[0]);
```

Comment: Neither do not work: http://jsfiddle.net/4e6fH/3/ Why is that? If I use ID selector such as: http://jsfiddle.net/4e6fH/1/ it works fine

Comment: Could you please suggest me why this code is returning undefined to me. var input = document.getElementsByClassName('map_address'); for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i]); google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() { place = autocomplete.getPlace(); console.log(place); }); } Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `input` dom reference via the index `0`

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('.addressClass input')[0]);
```

or you can use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($('.addressClass input').get(0));
```

Comment: Could you please suggest me why this code is returning undefined to me. var input = document.getElementsByClassName('map_address');
   
        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i]);
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                console.log(place);
            });    
        }  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kamlesh Because of the scope of the variable `var input = document.getElementsByClassName('map_address');

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('CodeMirror-scroll')).forEach((el, idx) => {
  let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(el);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    console.log(place);
  });
})`

Comment: You are awesome, it works like charm. Thank a lot dear :)